# Android chrome magnification does not show iframe content

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, magnification

I met a problem in android chrome, see the screenshots:

1. No magnification
2. Arrow next is under the magnification but not shown
3. Toolbar is under the magnification but not shown

[image]

It is flipbook plugin from http://3dflipbook.net/ in the desktop version. Mobile version does not have magnification so it is ok.

When there was a div as a container - magnification worked well.

Device: Huawei Honor H60-L12 Android 4.4.2 Emotion UI 2.3, chrome - latest.

Also, I noticed unstable work with iframes z-index ordering.

Does anyone know how to fix the magnification?

Best regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Good news. After one of the chrome updates the issue disappeared.